# Is there a way to use graph theory/numpy functionality to optimize the tangled web problem?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, optimization, graph-theory

## The Problem:

Imagine you have an mxn array where each element in a row has an one-to-one "connection" to another element in the row below it. With this you are given a connection array which is m-1xn array and in each row there are random order of integers from 0 to n-1. The mth row encodes connections of the mth+1 row. example: [[0,2,1],[1,2,0]]. The first row reads the 0th element goes to the 0th index, the 1st element goes to 2nd index, and the 2nd element goes to the 1st index.

**Wanted Output**:[Tangled Web Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N0XI.png)
The array should be untangled so that each element's connection is in the same column

## My Logic through it:

My thought is to switch each of rows of the connection matrix. So [[0,2,1],[1,2,0]] results in [[0,2,1],[1,0,2]]. However once you have more rows since you are switching the mth+1 row, you need to switch all the rows after it since the connections need to be perserved. However the keep the connections working from the bottom up seems to be best. Example: [[0,2,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,0]] (applying [2,1,0] to last row)--> [[0,2,1],[2,1,0],[0,1,2]] (appying [0,2,1] to last two rows)--> [[0,2,1],[2,0,1],[0,2,1]]. But to keep the connections the same becomes an expensive process.

## My Code:

```python
np.random.seed(42)
array = np.random.random(1000*10001).reshape(10001,1000)
connections = np.zeros(1000*10000, dtype=int).reshape(10000,1000)
for i in range(10000):
    connections[i] = np.random.permutation(1000)
i_range = connections.shape[0]-2
indices = np.arange(i_range, -1,-1)

for i in indices:
    connections[i:] = connections[i:, connections[i]] #This is the expensive step
for i in range(connections.shape[0]):
    array[i+1] = array[i+1,connections[i]]
```

## Question:

I would imagine there is much easier way to do this with graph theory, numpy functionality or something else? So my quesiton is, what would be the best way to optimize this code in python? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you're trying to do. You've described the input, but not the output you're trying to produce.

Comment: I should have made the picture more clear. I've updated what I want the output to be: The array should be untangled so that each element's connection is in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```py
class node:
    def __init__(self,value=None,nextR=None,nextD=None,to_the_right=False):
        self.nextR=nextR
        self.nextD=nextD
        self.val=value
        self.dirR=to_the_right
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        o=self
        for i in range(index):
            o=o.next()
        return node(o.val,o.nextR,o.nextD,not o.dirR)
    '''
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        try:
            if self.next()==None:
                raise StopIteration
            return self.next()
        except:
            raise StopIteration
    '''
    def __len__(self):
        o=1
        n=self
        while n.next()!=None:
            o+=1
            n=n.next()
        return o
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
    def next(self):
        if self.dirR:
            o=self.nextR
        else:
            o=self.nextD
        if o!=None:
            o.dirR=self.dirR
        return o
    def __copy__(self):
        return node(self.val,self.nextR,self.nextD,self.dirR)
    def nodeList(n,right=False,v=None):
        l=list()
        while n>0:
            l.append(node(v,None,None,right))
            n-=1
        return l

#making the arrays (lists here)

array=[
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [10,11,12]
]

connections=[
    [0,2,1],
    [1,0,2],
    [0,1,2]
]

w=len(array[0])
h=len(array)

from copy import copy

W=node.nodeList(w)
c=W
for i in range(w):
    c[i].val=array[0][i]
    if i<w-1:
        c[i].nextR=c[i+1]
c=W
p=W[0]

for i in range(h-1):
    for j in range(w):
        if j==0:
            r=p
            c=node.nodeList(w)
        else:
            c[connections[i][j-1]].nextR=c[connections[i][j]]
        r.nextD=c[connections[i][j]]
        r=r.nextR
        c[j].val=array[i+1][j]
    p=p.nextD

for i in range(len(W[0])):
    for j in range(len(W[0][i])):
        print(W[0][i][j],end=" ")
    print()

'''
print()
for i in W:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end=" ")
    print()
'''
```

I am not certain how efficient of well thought-out this is. W[0] can be used as the output array. Somehow I messed up the part for making the object iterable.